# Java core dumped with safepoint.cpp:310 error

Tags: java, sockets

We were using jdk1.8.0_144 and it crashed with the following error.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
# Internal Error (safepoint.cpp:310), pid=8063, tid=0x00007faa0cc5b700
# guarantee(PageArmed == 0) failed: invariant
# 
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_144-b01) (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
# Java VM: Java Hotspot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
```